# Could not load type 'WebApp1._Default' in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

When I am running my ASP.NET application I will get an error

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApp1._Default'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp1._Default" %>
Line 2:
Line 3:

Source File: /Default.aspx    Line: 1

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Update your Question with hosting environment, are you using visual studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your DLL is in the bin folder. (Not bin/debug...).

Comment: This is my problem. I change my output path. Why this happen so?

Comment: It's by design, so visual studio allows you to compile different types of DLL. Release/Debug etc. It's something to be aware of really.

Comment: @Sauron Unlike Visual Studio that allows you to define a user-defined output directory, the hosting environment (IIS) looks only in bin. The configured output directory as defined by VS is usually a subdirectory of bin by default, so you have to edit the Build properties of the project for your selected build configuration to change it.

Answer (score 4):

have you set your web app directory as application in IIS?

I have seen this error many times for different reasons.

1. Check namespace
2. dependent dll versions
3. Visual studio clean and compile again.
4. clean temp asp.net files "Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files"

Comment: I ran into the same problem and fixed it by setting up the web app directory correctly. I had chosen the wrong application pool (not asp.net 4.0)

Answer (score 3):

Did you rename the namespace or class name in the code-behind file? Open the code-behind file and verify that the namespace for the page is called `WebApp1` and that the class is called `_Default`, or update the `Inherits`-attribute in the aspx page header to fit the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified your **_Default** class is under the namespace **WebApp1** in Default.aspx.cs file ?

Please check.

Answer (score 0):

For me somehow the code-behind file got removed from the project.  They showed up with a different icon in the solution explorer.  I just had to expand the ASPX line to see the code behind and then right-click and add it to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Please try under "Project Settings/Build" set OutputPath to "bin\" not "bin\debug". this was my problem.