# IIS 6.0 web application - Does the entire "website" need to be an "application"?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis-6

I had a website hosted in IIS. One small section of it needed asp.net. So I just right-clicked that section/directory and made it an application and a virtual directory.

Is that alright? Or does the entire "website" need to be made into an application and virtual directory?

The reason I ask is that when I try to browse to the aspx page in this "application", I am getting a parser error message "Could not load type...MyCodeBehindType" in the page directive, which seems to me to indicate that it is not finding the dll's, or even the code behind class files (which are clearly in the same directory).

**EDIT:**

If I do it this way, with only a subfolder of my website actually being a *web application*, where do I put the dlls? In a bin folder of the website the web application is within? Or in a bin folder of the web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making just a folder within a website, an application, should be fine. I usually have to remember to change the version of ASP.NET from 1.1 to 2.x, that may be what's causing the error.

In order to test the configuration, start with a blank test page (blank.aspx) with just HTML. If the HTML shows up, you know IIS is serving .NET pages.

If there is a problem with ASP.NET not being correctly registered for IIS, you could try re-registering it. Open the following folder:

`%WindowsDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\x.x.x\`

and run:

`aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

Comment: Is it possible for different applications to run different versions of .NET, i.e. should I check to make sure that the application I created within the website is running 2.x? Or is this a higher level setting within IIS that would cover all websites?

Comment: Ok so I created a generic webpage by just adding a new webform to the project. I got an error again in the page directive, Could not load type 'MyNamespace.WebForm1'.

Comment: This question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707835/could-not-load-type-webapp1-default-in-asp-net, suggests that it has to do with the dll not being in the bin. This leads me to the other part of the question . . . see my edit in my question for the other part of my question...