# I am running my application and got this error

Tags: asp.net

Code :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site2.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserManagement.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestAutomationAccelerator.UserMangaement" %>

error:

    Server Error in '/' Application.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestAutomationAccelerator.UserManagement'.
```

Source Error:

```
    Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserManagement.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestAutomationAccelerator.UserManagement" %>
    Line 2:  
    Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>


    Source File: /UserManagement.aspx   Line: 1 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: This error is telling you that the runtime cannot find the `TestAutomationAccelerator.UserManagement` class. Does that class definitely exist? Have you compiled your code?

Comment: namespace TestAutomationAccelerator
{
    public partial class UserMangaement : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

Comment: Is this site hosted in IIS, or IIS Express from a Visual Studio debug session? Do any other pages in the project work? If you create a new project with a single page, does that work? Does this code fail on your machine only, or also on your colleagues' machines?

Comment: this site is hosted on IIS express.This Page Works fine but the problem is I have used a save button on this page to save user details .after saving details this page automatically redirects to this error page

Comment: Do not post your code in comments. Relevant code belongs *in the question itself*. And it's best to copy/paste code rather than retyping it. Your error message says it can't find type `TestAutomationAccelerator.UserManagement` but the code in your comment says you have type `TestAutomationAccelerator.UserMangaement`. Is that a typo in your question, or is that how it actually appears in your application? If the latter, then you've found your problem.

Comment: Do you have see that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707835/could-not-load-type-webapp1-default-in-asp-net?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Your class is called `UserMangaement` but your page directive is told to find class `UserManagement`. Note the different spellings. You need to make them match so it can find the correct path.

Always verify obvious stuff like this *before* posting a question on Stack Overflow. If it says it can't load a certain type, then verify that the type exists.